# Google Scripts: Create Datepicker for Date Input

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker, calendar, google-sheets

I'm looking to create a datepicker in Google Scripts (javascript) for a spreadsheet, so that a user can input a date by selecting a date from the calendar.

This datepicker would be part of a configuration function, and the input value is not entered anywhere in the physical spreadsheet its, but is stored as a property, for use in a GET request by the script populating the sheet.

After trawling through the Google Script documentation, I haven't found any such class or methods to build a datepicker.

Currently, I just have an input box that says "Please enter your date in the following format: DD/MM/YYYY", but it would look much nicer, and input validation would be simpler if we had a calendar menu.

Thank you.

Note: This is completely unrelated to Google Calendar events.

Answer (score 0):

**Script**

you may like to adopt one of bootstrap date pickers.

References:

1. How to make [custom html dialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/#serve_html_as_a_web_app)
2. Date Picker [bootstrap Example](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

I've found possible to implement this [sample in my google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NDSTLdJKXduh74Tgxh1XQyKynQZSESazQqL41Bwo-qI/edit?usp=sharing).

The result looks like this:

[image]

---

**In-cell solution**

Already has this function.

[Look at this post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/42543/118810) on Webapps site.

I've coppied it down:

1. Right-click the selection you want to have the date picker show up for (i.e. single cell, entire row, entire column)
2. and then open data validation.
3. Set Criteria: Date is a valid date and click Save.
4. Now just double-click the cell!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it isn't exactly what I'm looking for. I'm not looking to put a datepicker into any cell. I have my own "Configure Settings" function that I run, which shows this input box. The value inserted into this box isn't actually stored anywhere on the sheet, but it is stored as a variable in the script, for use in a GET Request. Perhaps I should have stated this in the question.